# Casting error in Ecto changesets

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have the following model (for a chat room) which I'm having problem with while using changesets:

```
defmodule Elemental.TxChat.Room do
  use Elemental.TxChat.Web, :model

  schema "rooms" do
    field :name, :string

    # Foreign key indicating which user created this room
    # One user can create any number of rooms 
    belongs_to :created_by, Elemental.TxChat.User
    field :created_from_app, :integer

    many_to_many :members, Elemental.TxChat.User, join_through: "rooms_users"

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:name, :created_by, :created_from_app])
    |> validate_required([:name, :created_by, :created_from_app])
  end
end
```

I then thought, I'd try to pass an empty struct to the changeset  and see the error it produced. So I did (after aliasing):

```
iex(4)> c = Room.changeset(%Room{}, %{})
** (RuntimeError) casting assocs with cast/3 is not supported, use cast_assoc/3 instead
       (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:440: Ecto.Changeset.type!/2
       (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:415: Ecto.Changeset.process_param/8
     (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1151: Enum."-map_reduce/3-lists^mapfoldl/2-0-"/3
     (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1151: Enum."-map_reduce/3-lists^mapfoldl/2-0-"/3
       (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:391: Ecto.Changeset.do_cast/7
    (tx_chat) web/models/room.ex:19: Elemental.TxChat.Room.changeset/2
```

I then thought that models that had `belongs_to`, etc., worked with `cast_assoc`, so I changed the function name. And now:

```
iex(4)> c = Room.changeset(%Room{}, %{})
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Ecto.Changeset.cast_assoc/3
       (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:518: Ecto.Changeset.cast_assoc(%Elemental.TxChat.Room{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "rooms">, created_by: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :created_by is not loaded>, created_by_id: nil, created_from_app: nil, id: nil, inserted_at: nil, members: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :members is not loaded>, name: nil, updated_at: nil}, %{}, [:name, :created_by, :created_from_app])
    (tx_chat) web/models/room.ex:19: Elemental.TxChat.Room.changeset/2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you just change `cast` to `cast_assoc`? Try `|> cast(params, [:name, :created_from_app]) |> cast_assoc(:created_by)`.

Comment: Let me know if that worked and I'll post an answer with explanation.

Comment: @Dogbert So that's what the mystery was! I was indeed stupid enough to simply replace `cast` with `cast_assoc`. Thank you very much for helping me out every time . . . really appreciate it. Please do post an answer and explain.

Comment: Are you passing fields for a _new_ User to `Room.changeset` in `created_by` or passing an integer in `created_by_id`? I reread the documentation and it looks like `cast_assoc` is not what you want unless you want to insert a new user when creating a Room.

Comment: @Dogbert The users are pre-existing. I just want to associate a user with a room when that user creates a room.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As clarified in the comments, you want to associate an existing User with a new Room. You can do this by adding `created_by_id` in the list of fields passed to `cast`, an `assoc_constraint(:created_by)` and then sending the user's id in the key `created_by_id` to `Room.changeset/2`. This should work:

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:name, :created_by_id, :created_from_app])
  |> validate_required([:name, :created_by_id, :created_from_app])
  |> assoc_constraint(:created_by)
end
```

And then to create a Room:

```
Room.changeset(%Room{}, %{name: "foo", created_by_id: 1, created_from_app: 1})
|> Repo.insert
```